# Symbolically solving coupled partial differential equations

Tags: linear-algebra, partial-differential-equations

The essential nature of what I'm asking can be illustrated by this system of equations:
$$\begin{pmatrix}
 a_{11}\partial_x & a_{12}\partial_y \\
 a_{21}\partial_x & a_{22}\partial_y
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
 f_1(x, y) \\
 f_2(x, y)
\end{bmatrix}
=
\Lambda
\begin{bmatrix}
 f_1(x, y) \\
 f_2(x, y)
\end{bmatrix}$$
where the $a$'s are constant coefficients, $\Lambda$ is a constant, and the $f$'s are the unknown functions I'll need to find.
We can assume that some sort of boundary conditions will be provided.
I thought I knew how to solve this system, but I can't seem to figure it out.

The first "obvious" technique, separation of variables, doesn't seem to work, because if I take the candidate solution
$$\begin{align}
 f_1(x, y) &= X_1(x)Y_1(y) &
 f_2(x, y) &= X_2(x)Y_2(y)
\end{align}$$
I get
$$\begin{align}
 a_{11} X_1'(x) Y_1(y) + a_{12} X_2(x) Y_2'(y) = \Lambda X_1(x)Y_1(y) \\
 a_{21} X_1'(x) Y_1(y) + a_{22} X_2(x) Y_2'(y) = \Lambda X_2(x)Y_2(y) \\
\end{align}$$
and I can't cancel out all the factors not involving a particular independent variable, as I would be able to with a single PDE or uncoupled system.

I can make some progress using a Fourier transform,
$$f_i(x, y) = \iint \tilde f_i(k_x, k_y) e^{-i(k_x x + k_y y)}\mathrm{d}k_x\mathrm{d}k_y$$
after which the system becomes
$$\iint \mathrm{d}k_x\mathrm{d}k_y
(-i)
\begin{pmatrix}
 a_{11}k_x & a_{12}k_y \\
 a_{21}k_x & a_{22}k_y
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
 \tilde f_1(k_x, k_y) \\
 \tilde f_2(k_x, k_y)
\end{bmatrix}
e^{-i(k_x x + k_y y)}
=
\Lambda
\iint \mathrm{d}k_x\mathrm{d}k_y
\begin{bmatrix}
 \tilde f_1(k_x, k_y) \\
 \tilde f_2(k_x, k_y)
\end{bmatrix}
e^{-i(k_x x + k_y y)}$$
and I can show using orthogonality of the Fourier basis functions that
$$-i
\underbrace{
\begin{pmatrix}
 a_{11}k_x & a_{12}k_y \\
 a_{21}k_x & a_{22}k_y
\end{pmatrix}
}_{AK}
\begin{bmatrix}
 \tilde f_1(k_x, k_y) \\
 \tilde f_2(k_x, k_y)
\end{bmatrix}
=
\Lambda
\begin{bmatrix}
 \tilde f_1(k_x, k_y) \\
 \tilde f_2(k_x, k_y)
\end{bmatrix}$$
for each $(k_x, k_y)$.

This is very similar to the eigensystem definition for the matrix $-iAK$, but not the same because the eigenvalues of $-iAK$ come out as functions of $k_{x,y}$,
$$\lambda_k^{\pm} = -\frac{i}{2}\Bigl(a_{11}k_x + a_{22}k_y \pm \sqrt{(a_{11}k_x - a_{22}k_y)^2 + 4 a_{12}a_{21}k_x k_y}\Bigr)$$
whereas if I'm going to solve this system, the eigenvalues would have to be independent of $k_{x,y}$ because $\Lambda$ is a constant. (I think.) So I'm basically stuck here. Can anyone point me in the right direction on how to solve this system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints to the question (v1):

1. Let us rewrite the eq. system as 
   $$\tag{1} \sum_{j=1}^2a_{ij}\frac{\partial f_i(x)}{\partial x^j}~=~\Lambda f_i(x),\qquad i~\in~\{1,2\},\qquad\text{(no implicit sum over }i.) $$
2. We will here for simplicity assume that the matrix $(a_{ij})$ is invertible, and leave the singular case to the reader.
3. Define new variables $(y_1,y_2)$ via the relation
   $$\tag{2} x_j~=~ \sum_{i=1}^2y_i a_{ij},\qquad j~\in~\{1,2\}.$$
4. Show that eq. (1) simplifies to 
   $$\tag{3} \frac{\partial g_i(y)}{\partial y^i}~=~\Lambda g_i(y),\qquad i~\in~\{1,2\},\qquad\text{(no implicit sum over }i,) $$
   where we have introduced the notation $g_i(y)=f_i(x)$.
5. Show that eq. (3) has the complete solution
   $$\tag{4} g_i(y)~=~e^{\Lambda y_i}h_i(y_{3-i}),\qquad i~\in~\{1,2\}, \qquad\text{(no implicit sum over }i,)$$
   where $h_1,h_2$ are arbitrary functions in one variable each.

Comment: I think that should do it. If something goes wrong applying this to my real case (which is a bit more complicated), I'll post a followup question.

Comment: How do you bring the system of OP to your Eq.(1)? It doesn't look consistent. I also tag the author @DavidZ

Comment: @apt45: Thanks for the feedback. It seems you're right: The LHS of eq. (1) should be  $\sum_{j=1}^2a_{ij}\frac{\partial f_j(x)}{\partial x^j}$ instead...

Comment: @Qmechanic but then the following steps are not right. Probably your answer was just a "hint"? Yet it does not apply to the system of the OP.

Comment: Yes I know; I hope to find time to fix it.

Comment: @Qmechanic great!

Comment: I don't remember the real problem I was working on at the time, but since I didn't post another question about this, odds are that this hint was enough to figure it out.